# Email Intent - Email body not working

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an application that calculates a score and sends that score via email. Everything works, but the body of the email. The code is as follows:

XML

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:onClick="submitScore"
    android:text="@string/submit"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
```

In my `MainActivity.java` I created a global variable that I update to write the body of the email, which I update with the score. When the `onClick` is called, it composes the email.

```
int finalScore = 0;
String emailBody = "";

public void grade(View view) {
    // bunch of code here
    constructMessage(finalScore);
    finalScore = 0;
}

public void constructMessage(int score){
    emailBody = "Your total score is: " + score;
    System.out.println("In ConstructMessage - " + emailBody);
}

public void submitScore(View view){
    System.out.println("In submitScore - " + emailBody);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your score for the Quiz!");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is a test!");
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Android logcat shows the correct message on both prints (`Your total score is: x`).
The email Subject is correct, but the email Body is blank and I don't why. I tried adding `intent.setType("message/rfc822");` but it didn't help.

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content);
intent.setType("text/*");
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share using"));
```